# How to query embeddings for semantic search?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, bert-language-model, large-language-model, vector-search

I have 1000 description for some SKU merchandise and I want to generate inverse embedding mapping to do semantic search

For example here is what I have

```
item   description
item1  [word1, word2, word3, word4..........]
item2  [word1, word2_2, word3_3, word4_4..........]
```

As you can see `item1` and `item2` shares `word1`, but `item1` and `item2` has two different context, by generating embedding, we should be able to capture the context of each word

Here is how i generate embeddings

```
my_description = []
with open('/content/gdrive/My Drive/my.csv', 'r') as data:
    df = pd.read_csv(data, encoding = ('utf-8'),nrows=100)
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        my_str = row['description']
        my_description.append(my_str)



import torch
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
%matplotlib inline
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased',
output_hidden_states = True, # Whether the model returns all hidden-states.
)
model.eval()


text2 = company_description[0]

# Add the special tokens.
marked_text2 = "[CLS] " + text2 + " [SEP]"

# Split the sentence into tokens.
tokenized_text2 = tokenizer.tokenize(marked_text2)

# Map the token strings to their vocabulary indeces.
indexed_tokens2 = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenized_text2)

segments_ids2 = [1] * len(tokenized_text2)
tokens_tensor2 = torch.tensor([indexed_tokens2])
segments_tensors2 = torch.tensor([segments_ids2])

with torch.no_grad():
    outputs2 = model(tokens_tensor2, segments_tensors2)
    hidden_states2 = outputs2[2]

token_embeddings2 = torch.stack(hidden_states2, dim=0)
token_embeddings2.size()
token_embeddings2 = torch.squeeze(token_embeddings2, dim=1)
token_embeddings2.size()
token_embeddings2 = token_embeddings2.permute(1,0,2)
token_embeddings2.size()

token_vecs_cat2 = [] 

for token in token_embeddings2:
     cat_vec = torch.cat((token[-1], token[-2], token[-3], token[-4]), dim=0)
     token_vecs_cat2.append(cat_vec)
token_vecs_sum2 = []
import numpy as np
x_token = np.empty((0, 768))

for token in token_embeddings2:
    sum_vec = torch.sum(token[-4:], dim=0)
    token_vecs_sum2.append(sum_vec)
    x_token = np.concatenate((x_token, sum_vec.numpy().reshape((1,-1))), axis=0)
```

`x_token` would be the embeddings for all my word/token in one description
For example say that item1 has 500 tokens and embedding is 700
the shape of `x_token` would be (500 x 700)

so for each item i would have something like this

```
item        token          embeddings
item 1      token 1        [x1,x2,x3,.....] 
item 1      token 2        [x1,x2,x3,.....] 
....
item 2      token 1_2      [x1,x2,x3,.....] 
item 2      token 2_2      [x1,x2,x3,.....] 
....
item n      token 1_n      [x1,x2,x3,.....] 
item n      token 2_n      [x1,x2,x3,.....]
```

Now my question is how do i perform search

If my search query is a sentence

"word1 word2 word3.....wordn"

If I generate embedding for each word in the sentence and perform ANN for top 10 nearest neighbor for each token

If my query has 10 tokens, I would get 100 item description back (10 for each token)
In that case, how do i shortlist to top 10 item description? Which token should i use?

```
query = [token1, token2.......tokenN]

                   top 10 nearest_neighbor's item, 
query_token1 ->    [itemx1_1, itemx1_2, itemx1_10]
query_token2 ->    [itemx2_1, itemx2_2, itemx2_10]
```

Am i doing semantic search wrong?